# The 'this' keyword in functions

Tags: javascript, function, object, this

Taken from ejohn.org:

```
function katana(){ 
  this.isSharp = true; 
} 
katana(); 
assert( isSharp === true, "A global object now exists with that name and value." );
```

This comes out as true.

Could anyone explain this? 
Inside the function we see `this.isSharp = true`, doesn't that create an `object` which should have the propery `isSharp`, and its value would be `true`? (I would think the object is katana, since it calls the function, so `katana.isSharp` would be `true`).
In other words, what exactly does the `this` refer to?

How come `isSharp` is created as an object?

Comment: this possibly refers to window here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is really wonky in JavaScript.

`this` is determined based on the context surrounding a function call, not as a property of the function. If a function is called like this:

```
f()
```

then `this` will refer to the global object. Adding a property to the global object is equivalent to adding a global variable, as you saw happen. If a function is called like this:

```
foo.f()
```

then `this` will refer to `foo`. Example:

```
> function printx() { console.log(this.x); }
> x = 300
> obj1 = {x: 20, printx: printx};
> obj2 = {x: 50, printx: printx};
> printx();
300
> obj1.printx();
20
> obj2.printx();
50
```

Finally, if a function is called like this:

```
new f()
```

then a new object is created, `this` refers to that new object, and the expression `new f()` evaluates to either that new object, or the object returned by `f()` if `f()` returns an object.

It's all in the spec. Very weird.

Answer (score 2):

You don't use `new`, so `this` is the global object (`window`) in the function.

```
katana();
```

is really

```
window.katana(); // the passed context is window
```

That's why the assertion `isSharp===true`, which tests in fact `window.isSharp`, returns `true`.

If you want to create a new instance of `katana`, use `new katana()`, and then `this` will be the new instance inside the function, leaving `window.isSharp` untouched.

Answer (score 2):

> doesn't that create an object which should have the propery isSharp, and its value would be true?

No, because the function was not invoked as a constructor. If you had `var obj = new katana()`, then you'd get an object with an `isSharp` property. Otherwise, it's just a function call, so what should `this` be? JavaScript doesn't know, so it decides it's undefined and falls back to the global object (unless in strict mode).

Determining the value of `this` inside functions in JavaScript can be confusing, because it's determined dynamically, depending on how the function is called. The basic rules are, `this` will be the global object unless:

- the function is called as an object method (then this will be the object), or
- the function is called as a constructor, with the new operator (in which case this will point to the new object being constructed)

More details on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the object context of the call.

In your case it is `window.katana();`
So `this` refers to `window`