# How "this" is looked up in callback of Javascript

Tags: javascript, callback, this

I have confused myself in the following case:

```
function foo() {
}

foo.prototype.bar1 = function() {
  console.log(this); // shows "Window"!!
}

foo.prototype.bar2 = function(func) {
  func();
}

var f = new foo();
f.bar2(f.bar1);
```

How/Why could the result of console.log(this) is "Window"? I thought no matter how you call public function of a class here,  "this" should always refer to "foo".

And also what is right way to avoid this kind of error?

Thanks

Comment: The rules are no different than any other function invocation (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382165/why-do-i-lose-the-context-of-this-in-javascript). `Function.prototype.bind` (or an emulation) can be useful here, as can general closures.

Comment: You can use `func.apply(this)` to get expected behavior, I think.

Comment: `func.call(this)` should do.

Comment: @WaleedKhan But that's a special case that works *specifically* here because the ThisBinding when `bar2` is executed is "expected".

Comment: this keyword is quite a complex issue in js. It invovles: window object, prototype, call/apply method and probably more. I recommend this book: javscript enlightment. Very helpful, I think http://www.javascriptenlightenment.com/JavaScript_Enlightenment.pdf

Comment: See my previous answer to this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628#13441628

Answer (score 1):

When you do `f.bar2(f.bar1)`, you're passing a reference of bar1 to bar2; inside bar2, it's only known as "func", and the connection with f is lost. [The value of `this` is determined dynamically when the function is invoked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). If you invoke f.bar1(), this will be f, but when you invoke func(), it's undefined, and will fall back to the global object (window).

I have [explained this earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15507194/825789) as follows:

> The basic rules are, this will be the global object unless:
>
> - the function is called as an object method (then this will be the
>     object), or
> - the function is called as a constructor, with the new
>     operator (in which case this will point to the new object being
>     constructed)

One way to avoid that is to create a bound function and pass that:

```
f.bar2(f.bar1.bind(f));
```

Note that Function.prototype.bind is not supported by older browsers, so you might need a polyfill (there's one available on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)).

In the simple scenario you presented, you can do what elclanrs suggests in his comment, as the target this is available inside bar2:

```
func.call(this);
```